# How to display sundays in a month?

Tags: php, date

I have been trying to get the answer for this question and after some R&D i have come up with the solution too

```
$begin = new DateTime('2014-11-01');
$end = new DateTime('2014-11-30');
$end = $end->modify('+1 day');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

foreach ($daterange as $date) {
    $sunday = date('w', strtotime($date->format("Y-m-d")));
    if ($sunday == 0) {
        echo $date->format("Y-m-d") . "<br>";
    } else {
        echo'';
    }
}
```

Comment: If any other date is needed then use 0=>sunday,1=>monday,2=>tuesday,3=>wednesday.. so on

Comment: So, what is the solution?

Comment: did you need to display all sundays in current month?

Comment: @Chilion
i have posted the solution. The code itself is the solution. the last else section can be removed if not needed.

Comment: yes @VIVEK-MDU this will display all the sundays.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, and as such the Q needs to be an actual question, not just code which could help someone else. If you have a good Q&A pair, you can post a question and an answer, however I doubt this particular code will help anyone else to be honest as it's localised to your own code.

Answer (score 6):

Try this way:

```
$begin  = new DateTime('2014-11-01');
$end    = new DateTime('2014-11-30');
while ($begin <= $end) // Loop will work begin to the end date 
{
    if($begin->format("D") == "Sun") //Check that the day is Sunday here
    {
        echo $begin->format("Y-m-d") . "<br>";
    }

    $begin->modify('+1 day');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another method for shown all sundays in current month:

```
<?php
    function getSundays($y, $m)
{
    return new DatePeriod(
        new DateTime("first sunday of $y-$m"),
        DateInterval::createFromDateString('next sunday'),
        new DateTime("last day of $y-$m 23:59:59")
    );
}

foreach (getSundays(2014, 11) as $sunday) {
    echo $sunday->format("l, Y-m-d\n");
}
?>
```

Refer this [Codepad.viper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KTL8U6)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for sundays

```
function getSundays($y,$m){ 
    $date = "$y-$m-01";
    $first_day = date('N',strtotime($date));
    $first_day = 7 - $first_day + 1;
    $last_day =  date('t',strtotime($date));
    $days = array();
    for($i=$first_day; $i<=$last_day; $i=$i+7 ){
        //$days[] = $i;  //this will give days of sundays
        $days[] = "$y-$m-".$i;  //dates of sundays
    }
    return  $days;
}

$days = getSundays(2016,04);
print_r($days);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this one to find Sundays of the current month.

```
$month  = date('m');
$year  = date('Y');
$days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month,$year);
for($i = 1; $i<= $days; $i++){
   $day  = date('Y-m-'.$i);
   $result = date("l", strtotime($day));
   if($result == "Sunday"){
   echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($day)). " ".$result."<br>";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for faster result we don't need to loop for full 31 days, we only need first Sunday date.

```
<?php
// change to "this month" for current month
$day  = new DateTime('first day of July 2022'); 
for ($i = 1; $i < 8; $i++)
{
    if ($day->format("D") == "Sun")
    { 
        // first sunday found, increment with 7
        while ($i <= 31)
        {
            echo $day->format("Y-m-d") . "\n";
            $i += 7;
            $day->modify("+7 day");
        }
        break;
    }

    $day->modify("+1 day");
}
```